# How to communicate AngularJS's $http routes and APIs developed in C Programming

Tags: c, angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I have made web application GUI using AngularJS, Bootstrap, HTML, CSS.
Backend team are developing APIs in C Programing.

So how my routes in $http request (sending from factory) will communicate to C Programing API (Controller) to get data or to perform related operations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would just need the URI and the Async request would look like this:

```
    $http.get('URI goes here').then(
            function (response) {
                //success
                vm.data = response;
            },
            function (response) {
                //fail
                console.log("error");
            }
        );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. But this part I have already done. I want to know is: how my URI will recognize the API in Server side script (C Programming).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn the concepts of Web API's. Basically the server (C written in your case?) responds to various HTTP requests (GET, POST, PUT, etc..). By defining a Web API you simply state that for some http request for a specific path - there's gonna be a meaningful response.

For example here's a Web API:

```
GET /api/users - list users
GET /api/users/{id} - get a specific user
POST /api/users/{id} - update specific user
```

To **consume** this endpoint (`/api/users`) you can use `$resource` or `$http` like so:

```
var UserFactory = $resource('/api/users/:id');
var userlist = UserFactory.query();
var user = UserFactory.get({id: 123});
user.$promise.then(function(){
 user.balance = 100000000;
 user.$save();
});
```

Basically in the background angular translates `$resource` calls to HTTP requests.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. But I have already done angular part ($http request with specific URI). I want to know is: how my URI will recognize the API in Server side script (C Programming).

Comment: Your URI won't recognize anything. you're specifying the **path** to which it should receive a proper response. Your backend team will define API paths for you to consume (use).

Comment: We all doing this work together. No one have knowledge about this communication between C program Web API & AngularJS's $http in my team. So please, help if C program example code u may know. T.I.A.